# CountIf on a range from different workbook

Tags: excel, for-loop, external, countif

I have been trying to find the root cause of this issue for a long time, but to no avail.

I am trying to count the number of instances a specific text occurs in another workbook (in this case the instance is "42.1" and the workbook name will be contained in Filename1).  For some reason, when I execute the countif directly in the sheet, it yields to the correct answer (which should be 2).  But whenever I run the code below, it gives me 3.

All the references appear OK since I manually called each value from another workbook and there was no issue.  Could you please help ?

Please diregard CounttIfV, it is essentially equivalent to the application function CountIf and I can use both interchangeably.

---

```
'manually define the latest S&OP input file
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
Shapes("DisplayFilename").TextFrame.Characters.Text = filename

'activate the S&OP Workbook
Filename1 = Split(filename, "\")(UBound(Split(filename, "\")))
Workbooks.Open (Filename1)
Workbooks(Filename1).Activate

'define the correct S&OP worksheet regardless of the date
For Each ws_mould In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws_mould.Name Like "*Mould*" Then
        Worksheets(ws_mould.Name).Activate
        active_ws = ws_mould.Name
    End If
Next ws_mould

Workbooks(Filename1).Activate
Set CellRange = Workbooks(Filename1).Worksheets(active_ws).Range(Worksheets(active_ws).Cells(27, 45), Worksheets(active_ws).Cells(53, 45))
'NumBlades = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(CellRange)
NumBlades = Module3.COUNTIFv(CellRange, "??42.1#*")
Shapes("DisplayFilename").TextFrame.Characters.Text = active_ws
```

Comment: Function COUNTIFv(Rin As Range, Condition As Variant) As Long
'Same as Excel COUNTIF worksheet function, except does not count
'cells that are hidden
Dim A As Range
Dim Csum As Long
Csum = 0
For Each A In Vis(Rin).Areas
Csum = Csum + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(A, Condition)
Next A
COUNTIFv = Csum
End Function

Comment: Function Vis(Rin As Range) As Range
'Returns the subset of Rin that is visible
Dim Cell As Range
Application.Volatile
Set Vis = Nothing
For Each Cell In Rin
If Not (Cell.EntireRow.Hidden Or Cell.EntireColumn.Hidden) Then
If Vis Is Nothing Then
Set Vis = Cell
Else
Set Vis = Union(Vis, Cell)
End If
End If
Next Cell
End Function

Comment: This is Module 3... it contains those two functions.  They are not highly relevant since they do not influence the answer.